# How to add the subreport dynamically to mainreport body ending part using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, subreport

i added new subreport dynamically based on condition to main report ending of the body, my code is

```
int left=10;
int top=20;
int width=50;
int height=50;
report.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreportEx("Test", @"C:\test-sub.rpt", report.ReportClientDocument.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.PageFooterArea.Sections[0], left, top, width, height);
```

it is working fine to add the sub report but it shows footer left side small image , i can try to increase the above value(height,width) not showing the small image also, when i click the image subreport displayed in another window, but i have to show the full subreport end of the body please help me any one....

Answer (score 0):

Try this to enable 'can grow' property:

```
  Dim obj As SubreportObject = report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects('Test')
  obj.ObjectFormat.EnableCanGrow = True
```